# Shortcode not work in picture source srcset tag

Tags: images, shortcode

I have in my WP plugin:

```
<picture>
    <source srcset="[bloginfo key='template_url']/images/image.webp" type="image/webp">
    <img src="[bloginfo key='template_url']/images/image.png">
</picture>
```

In a browser, `img src` code is OK, but on `srcset` it still says `[bloginfo key='template_url']`. What am I missing about shortcodes and the srcset attribute, so it will display in the right way?

Comment: This should not happen if your code snippet is actually one string that is evaluated at the same time. The different outcome suggests the snippet is handled differently. Could you give some more context?

Comment: This is my snippet:

function bloginfo_shortcode( $atts ) {
    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
        'key' => '',
    ), $atts));
    return get_bloginfo($key);
}
add_shortcode('bloginfo', 'bloginfo_shortcode');

I test this <a href="[bloginfo key='template_url']/images/image.png">test</a> and it works. I think it is something about the tag source, may be.

Comment: The shortcode only does a search and replace. It won't be the source of the problem. Some other code is messing with the snippet, disabling the shortcode on the source tag.

Comment: I can't find the relevant post on make.wordpress.org to be able to post a definitive answer, but I don't believe shortcodes are allowed inside HTML attributes for security reasons. Not to mention that is is an unintended use of their functionality. What problem are you trying to solve here?

Answer (score 0):

i fix this with a new shortcode that generates the entire tag. Like this:

```
function generate_image_tag($atts) {
    $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
        'img' => '',
        'title' => '',
        'theme_url' => get_bloginfo('template_url'),
    ), $atts );
    
    //File path details
    $file_info = pathinfo($atts['img']);
    $file_dir = $file_info['dirname'] != '.' ? $file_info['dirname'].'/' : '';
    $file_url = $file_dir . $file_info['filename'];
    
    $output = '<picture>
                <source srcset="'.$atts['theme_url'].'/images/'.$file_url.'.webp" type="image/webp">
                <img src="'.$atts['theme_url'].'/images/'.$atts['img'].'">
            </picture>';
    
    return $output;
}
add_shortcode('generate_image', 'generate_image_tag');


[generate_image img="image.png" title="Title"]
```

I think maybe something in WP is wrong, and its a bug. None shortcode works in `<source>` tag. Regards! :)